# Schemas validity error : element this element is not expected

Tags: xml, xsd, informatica

While running xmllint on an XML file created from an Informatica target, I'm getting the error below.  XSD and XML excerpts are below as well.  In the XML, I'm seeing data populated, so I am confused as to why I'm getting the error?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  FYI, I'm totally new to XML, so please bear with me.

Error -

> tac_mps_xml_generator_000246917_04012015.xml:171: element moday1: Schemas validity error : Element 'moday1': This element is not expected. Expected is ( month_day1 ).
> tac_mps_xml_generator_000246917_04012015.xml fails to validate

#### XSD excerpt -

```
<xs:complexType name="MoDayType">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="month_day"> <xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <xs:maxLength value="5"/> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="renderingphys" type="nameDetlType"/>
  <xs:element name="patienttotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
  <xs:element name="proceduretotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
  <xs:element name="mintotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="hoursbilleddetlType">
 <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="moday1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="MoDayType"/> 
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

#### XML -

```
 <moday1>
        <month_day/>
        <renderingphys>
          <fname/>
          <mname/>
          <lname/>
          <suffix/>
        </renderingphys>
        <patienttotal></patienttotal>
        <proceduretotal></proceduretotal>
        <mintotal></mintotal>
      </moday1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that in the interest of creating a minimal example exhibiting the issue, you've accidentally pruned away the problem.

Your XML:

```
<moday1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <month_day/>
  <renderingphys>
    <fname/>
    <mname/>
    <lname/>
    <suffix/>
  </renderingphys>
  <patienttotal></patienttotal>
  <proceduretotal></proceduretotal>
  <mintotal></mintotal>
</moday1>
```

Is valid against your XSD (with a root element added and an inconsequential missing type clipped) with no errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.01">

  <xs:element name="moday1" type="MoDayType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="MoDayType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="month_day">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="renderingphys"/>
      <xs:element name="patienttotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
      <xs:element name="proceduretotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
      <xs:element name="mintotal" type="xs:integer" default="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="hoursbilleddetlType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="moday1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="MoDayType"/> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Since your error indicates that the `moday1` element was unexpected, you'll have to consider the context in which the `moday1` element appears.  The content model of its parent is likely calling for a sequence of elements different than that which you are providing.